# What is a DUART?

Tags: uart

I know what a UART is, in fact I have coded a UART in Verilog, but I don't know what a DUART is.

I've seen that name in Qormino's datasheet (https://www.e2v.com/shared/content/resources/File/documents/Qormino/QT10A/Qormino_line_flyer.pdf), in the interfaces sections:

> Interface options SerDes, USB 2.0, DUARTs, I2C, GPIO, eSPI,
>   SD/eSDHC/eMMC,DIU, PCIe, SATA, SRIO, GbE

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just an acronym for Double UART, from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver/transmitter#UART_models):

> A dual UART, or DUART, combines two UARTs into a single chip.
>   Similarly, a quadruple UART or QUART, combines four UARTs into one
>   package, such as the NXP 28L194. An octal UART or OCTART combines
>   eight UARTs into one package, such as the Exar XR16L788 or the NXP
>   SCC2698.